# Angular - Disabling button until all options are selected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, angular-directive

I want to disable next button until all the statements are selected, means making selecting an option mandatory. I've tried but I'm stuck on how to enable it after selecting all options?
Also, if I go back it shouldn't show disable button. Any help? **(SOLVED)**

**EDIT:**
My app has now 2 scenarios, 2 different kind of questions.

1st case is mcq type in which **only one option** is selectable.

2nd case, T/F **all option** can either be true or false.

The suggested solution works but I want it to be based on **questionType** not
questionNumber. As the latter won't be unique.
**HTML**

```
<div class="qitem qclose"
                   [ngClass]="{'qclose-active': item.selectAnswer?.dirty && (item.selectAnswer?.select == 'false')}"
                   (click)="changeFalse(j , item, searchQuiz.tfQuestionNumber);toggle(searchQuiz.tfQuestionNumber)">
                <i class="qitembox qclose-icon">F</i>
              </div>
              <div class="qitem qtick"
                   [ngClass]="{'qtick-active': item.selectAnswer?.dirty && (item.selectAnswer?.select == 'true')}"
                   (click)="changeTrue(j , item,searchQuiz.tfQuestionNumber);toggle(searchQuiz.tfQuestionNumber)">
                <i class="qitembox qtick-icon">T</i>
              </div>
```

**TS**

```
setQuestionAnswer(i,option,step,answer){
    console.log(option,i);
    /*Update question status in options array*/ 
    this.QuizData.map(res=>{
      console.log(res.tfQuestionNumber,step);
      if(res.tfQuestionNumber === step){
        res.options.map(res=>{
          if(res.id === option.id){
            res.status = answer;
          }
        })
      }
    });
    /*-----------------------------*/ 
    console.log(this.QuizData);

   /*Calculate total values selected*/ 
    this.totalConditions(option, step);
  /*-----------------------------*/ 
  }
```

**Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4yczgp**

Comment: While @Mr. Khans answer is well prepared, you question is missing essential code necessary to answer your question and your demo's html file have changed since the original post, causing some of the suggested ts to throw errors. This question benefits noone but you. (thats all I wanted to mention along with the downvote).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I was in a hurry and didn't have access to the laptop. I've updated my question with updated problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the status of each step with boolean value and also add value for your answer status as true or false to options array. You can do this by adding new property of status to `QuizData` array which contains data from API like this:

```
this.QuizData.forEach(x=>{
  x['status'] = true;
  x.selectAnswer = { select: '', dirty: '' };
  x.options.map((x, index)=>{
    x['id'] = index;
    x['status'] = null;
  })
})
```

If you notice, I have added ID property to each field which is used to fetch the answered question and updating its status like this:

```
  changeTrue(i, option, step) {
    this.setQuestionAnswer(i, option, step, true);

    option.selectAnswer = { select: 'true', dirty: 'true' };
  }


  setQuestionAnswer(i,option,step){
    console.log(option,i);
    /*Update question status in options array*/ 
    this.QuizData.map(res=>{
      console.log(res.tfQuestionNumber,step);
      if(res.tfQuestionNumber === step){ //=====> matching the current step
        res.options.map(res=>{
          if(res.id === option.id){ // =======> matching the current question and setting it to true or false
            res.status = answer;
          }
        })
      }
    });
    /*-----------------------------*/ 
    console.log(this.QuizData);

   /*Calculate total values selected*/ 
    this.totalConditions(option, step);
  /*-----------------------------*/ 
  }
```

Now to calculate total questions answered

```
  totalConditions(option,step){
    this.count= 0;
    let len = 0;
    this.QuizData.map(res=>{
      console.log(res.tfQuestionNumber,step);
      if(res.tfQuestionNumber === step){
        len= res.options.length;
        res.options.map(res=>{
          if(res.status !== null){
            this.count = this.count +1;
          }
        })
      }
    });
    if(this.count ===len){  // If all all questions answered then remove disable from button
      this.QuizData.map(res=>{
        if(res.tfQuestionNumber === step){
          res.status = false;  
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

And it's done. You can go back and forward as you please and the status won't change to disable. Hope it helps :)

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-quiz

**Scenario 2:**

If you have options as MCQs, in that case you can simply add this piece of code to toggle method().

```
toggle(step) { 
    this.buttonDisabled = false;

    this.QuizData.map(res=>{
      console.log(res.index,step);
      if(res.index === step){
        res.status = false; 
      }
    });
    console.log(this.QuizData); 

}
```

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-quiz-mcqs

Comment: No, the thing is the questions would be coming from an API and it doesn't have ID and status fields. I've just added this static data for practice usage. Your solution works great for this scenario.

Comment: alright! if you cant add them this way. Then add new keys in API like this :object[key]. Check the link I have updated.

Comment: Updated Answer for clarity

Comment: It is breaking when I'm adding more questions, why is that? I can't understand

Comment: What do you mean breaking? its working perfectly. i just added question 4 in the link. check it.

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated. I’ll try and mark it as solve

Comment: Another thing, this won’t work if I have Mcqs type questions and only 1 option to select, right?

Comment: Yes, that's a different scenario from this question. I only answered the question asked.

Comment: Can you help me that too? I updated a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f21i11

Comment: Alright but if my answer helped you please accept it and upvote it.

Comment: Sure, why not. I added both type of questions merged with your earlier solution

Comment: Done. Once you accept and vote my answer, I will provide the solution for other question

Comment: It's not accepted yet. I took my time out to answer a question, If it was helpful you are suppose to accept it.

Comment: Okay man, cuz I wanted to try it first and ask in case of any issue. I’m accepting it

Comment: I see, you’ve made it around questionNumber. Would it also work for questionType? Cuz I wanna do it for questionType cuz it’s unique for 2 type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

so I think that you should consider using reactive forms and make a Validator for when all formControls (you will have one for each question) are dirty.

My second suggestion is following the code that you wrote. Every time you call changeFalse or changeTrue you keep the count the numbers of answers made and then you set *this.buttonDisabled* accordingly if the count is equals to the number of question